# Count number of rows that have a specific word in a varchar (in postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I have a table similar to the below:

```
id | name    |    direction           |
--------------------------------------
1   Jhon       Washington, DC
2   Diego      Miami, Florida
3   Michael    Orlando, Florida
4   Jenny      Olympia, washington
5   Joe        Austin, Texas
6   Barack     Denver, Colorado
```

and I want to count how many people live in a specific state:

```
Washington 2
Florida    2
Texas      1
Colorado   1
```

How can I do this? (By the way this is just an question with an academic point of view )
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't that be only 1 for Washington? Because Jhon lives in DC, not in the state of Washington.

Comment: Not in my example! (I´m not from USA) :) Other way of see it is: I want to count how many "Washington", "Florida", ... words there are, regardless whether it is after or before "," That s a little bit harder, I think the only way to do it is with a PL/SQL function, not?

Answer (score 1):

Postgres offers the function `split_part()`, which will break up a string by a delimiter.  You want the second part (the part after the comma):

```
select split_part(direction, ', ', 2) as state, count(*)
from t
group by split_part(direction, ', ', 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially I would obtain the state from the direction field. Once you have that, it's quite simple:

```
SELECT state, count(*) as total FROM initial_table group by state.
```

To obtain the state, some functions depending on the dbms are useful. It depends on the language.

A possible pseudocode (given a function like substring_index of MySQL) for the query would be:

```
SELECT substring_index(direction,',',-1) as state, count(*) as total 
FROM initial_table group by substring_index(direction,',',-1)
```

Edit: As it is suggested above, the query should return 1 for the Washington state.

Answer (score 0):

My way do making such a queries is two-step - first, prepare fields you need, second, do you grouping or other calculation. That way you're following DRY principle and don't repeating yourself. I think CTE is the best tool for this:

```
with cte as (
   -- we don't need other fields, only state
   select
       split_part(direction, ', ', 2) as state
   from table1
)
select state, count(*)
from cte
group by state
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/19ede/1)

If you writing queries that way, it's easy to change grouping field in the future.

Hope that helps, and remember - readability counts! :)